# Android Studio and AndEngine - package does not exist

Tags: android, andengine, android-studio

I've got problem with adding AndEngine to Google Android Studio IDE.

1. I downloaded AndEngine from git and extract it to the folder.
2. In my existing project I clicked File>Project Structure>Modeles
3. In middle column green plus>new module>empty module and I selected AndEngine folder
4. In middle column i select my project then Dependencies>green plus at right>Module Dependency and I selected AndEngineModule.

When i try to run it there are errors like this:

```
Gradle: error: package org.andengine.engine.camera does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

I did the same! I am not sure how does it work exactly. But It seems that Android Studio uses libraries 'just for source' to find the libraries and then IDE uses Gradle like external build tool.

So I have created the **libs** directory in my project and move `*.jar` files there. I have added libraries files (`*.jar`) into project dependencies. Than I can use `org.andegine` package in my project sources but I had still the error so I have added dependencies also into `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    //compile files('libs/andengine.jar')  // for single file
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')  // for all files in directory
}
```